# How to add a site URL in every beginning of WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add my site URL (e.g.: test.com) on every beginning of my WordPress content, so it becomes like this:

> test.com - Lorem ipsum dollor bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dollor bla bla
>   bla Lorem ipsum dollor bla bla bla

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the result you want

```
<?php 
  var $content_fetch = explode('://',home_url());
  echo $content_fetch[1];
?>
```

you can echo like this

```
<?php echo $content_fetch[1];?> - Lorem ipsum dollor bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
//The filter for changing content without saving it in DB
add_filter( 'the_content', 'stender_filter_the_content');


function stender_filter_the_content( $content ) {

    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
        return "test.com -> ".$content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

This should add your text, on single posts, without changing it on the archives.

/*EDIT*/

Since you need it to be the first word, you might be able to do something like this instead.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); 

add_filter( 'the_content', 'stender_filter_the_content', 30 );


function stender_filter_the_content( $content ) {

    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
        return "test.com -> ".$content;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99 );
```

This is just an idea though - Haven't tested it.

Comment: Thx, it works, but slight littlebit different from my case

Comment: What you code do was show test.com on the top of content... what Im aimed was showing test.com before the first word of my content test.com - this is my content

Comment: hmm - the content runs through a function calla wpautop() - which generates html for you. you might be able to remove that filter, add the text, and add the filter again?

Comment: I have edited my answer, to include removal of the wpautop - you can test it out.

Comment: If this doesn't work, because you have divs or whatnot in your content, then you might need to take @frank s method of regexing

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to have this text on top of the large text probably. In that case you should use the `the_content` filter of Wordpress. You can define your own filter in a plugin or your theme's functions.php. For example:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'addUrlToContent', 10, 1);
```

As soon as `the_content()` is called somewhere in your theme this will execute the corersponding filter. So it generates the content, then sends the content to your filter function (in this case `addUrlToContent()`) which can do whatever it wants with the content before it is being returned to the theme. The last two arguments are the priority (you may have multiple filters on the same 'the_content' hook and want to execute them in a certain order) and the number of arguments you expect in the function. In this case just 1 ($content).

Your `addUrlToContent()` function should look like this:

```
function addUrlToContent($content) {
    $content = "test.com: " . $content;
    return $content;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thx for your great help, but I want to insert the test.com before the first word of the content.. what your code do was insert test.com on top of the content

Comment: also using this code, it also showed test.com on the excerpt too

Comment: To prevent it from appearing on archive pages use the if statement from Stender's comment (`if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() )`). With your other remark you mean that Wordpress wraps the content in `<p>` tags right? You can use PHP's substr_replace for that. You need to find the location of the first word using regex (not my speciality, but should be: `preg_match('/<.+>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/',$content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`. Now use `$content = substr_replace($content, "test.com: ", $matches[1][1], 0)`.